# QObject::connect: No such slot Menu::startCreate(window)

Tags: qt5, qt, c++

***menu.cpp***

```
#include "menu.h"

Menu::Menu(Cards *window, QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    window->setWindowTitle(tr("Cards - main menu"));
    QPushButton *createButton = new QPushButton(tr("&Create"));
    QPushButton *searchButton = new QPushButton(tr("&Search"));
    QPushButton *loginButton = new QPushButton(tr("&Login"));
    QPushButton *registerButton = new QPushButton(tr("&Register"));

    QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout;
    layout->addWidget(createButton, 2, 0);
    layout->addWidget(searchButton, 3, 0);
    layout->addWidget(loginButton, 4, 0);
    layout->addWidget(registerButton, 5, 0);
    setLayout(layout);

    connect(createButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(startCreate(window)));     // !
    connect(searchButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(startSearch(window)));     // ! БЯ
    connect(loginButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(startLogin(window)));       // ! ДА
    connect(registerButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(startRegister(window))); // !
}

void Menu::startCreate(Cards *window)
{
    CreateMenu *cm = new CreateMenu(window);
    window->setCentralWidget(cm);
}

void Menu::startSearch(Cards *window)
{
    SearchMenu *sm = new SearchMenu(window);
    window->setCentralWidget(sm);
}

void Menu::startLogin(Cards *window)
{
    LoginMenu *lm = new LoginMenu(window);
    window->setCentralWidget(lm);
}

void Menu::startRegister(Cards *window)
{
    RegisterMenu *rm = new RegisterMenu(window);
    window->setCentralWidget(rm);
}
```

***menu.h***

```
#ifndef MENU_H
#define MENU_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QPushButton>

#include "cards.h"
#include "create_menu.h"
#include "search_menu.h"
#include "login_menu.h"
#include "register_menu.h"

class Cards;

class Menu : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Menu(Cards *window, QWidget *parent = 0);

public slots:
    void startCreate(Cards *window);
    void startSearch(Cards *window);
    void startLogin(Cards *window);
    void startRegister(Cards *window);
};

#endif // MENU_H
```

Answer (score 2):

Сигнал `clicked()` не принимает аргументов и не может передать `Cards *window` в слот `startCreate()`.

Comment: Спасибо тебе.